# Ruby send vs __send__

Tags: ruby, syntax

I understand the concept of `some_instance.send` but I'm trying to figure out why you can call this both ways. The Ruby Koans imply that there is some reason beyond providing lots of different ways to do the same thing. Here are the two examples of usage:

```
class Foo
  def bar?
    true
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.send(:bar?)
foo.__send__(:bar?)
```

Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Some classes (for example the standard library's socket class) define their own `send` method which has nothing to do with `Object#send`. So if you want to work with objects of any class, you need to use `__send__` to be on the safe side.

Now that leaves the question, why there is `send` and not just `__send__`. If there were only `__send__` the name `send` could be used by other classes without any confusion. The reason for that is that `send` existed first and only later it was realized that the name `send` might also usefully be used in other contexts, so `__send__` was added (that's the same thing that happened with `id` and `object_id` by the way).

Comment: Also, [BasicObject](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html) (introduced in Ruby 1.9) only has `__send__`, not `send`.

Comment: Good answer. Might be even better if it mentioned `public_send`, which is often preferable to `send` anyways.

Answer (score 37):

If you *really* need `send` to behave like it would normally do, you should use `__send__`, because it won't (it shouldn't) be overriden. Using `__send__` is especially useful in metaprogramming, when you don't know what methods the class being manipulated defines. It could have overriden `send`.

Watch:

```
class Foo
  def bar?
    true
  end

  def send(*args)
    false
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.send(:bar?)
# => false
foo.__send__(:bar?)
# => true
```

If you override `__send__`, Ruby will emit a warning:

> warning: redefining `__send__' may
>   cause serious problems

Some cases where it would be useful to override `send` would be where that name is appropriate, like message passing, socket classes, etc.

Answer (score 12):

`__send__` exists so it can't be over-written by accident.

As for why `send` exists: I can't speak for anyone else, but `object.send(:method_name, *parameters)` looks nicer than `object.__send__(:method_name, *parameters)`, so I use `send` unless I *need* to use `__send__`.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from what others already told you, and what boils down to saying that `send` and `__send__` are two aliases of the same method, you might be interested in the third, somwhat different possibility, which is `public_send`. Example:

```
A, B, C = Module.new, Module.new, Module.new
B.include A #=> error -- private method
B.send :include, A #=> bypasses the method's privacy
C.public_send :include, A #=> does not bypass privacy
```

Update: Since Ruby 2.1, `Module#include` and `Module#extend` methods become public, so the above example would not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between send, `__send__`, and public_send is as follow.

1. send and `__send__` are technaically same as used to call Object's method, but the main difference is you can override the send method without any warning and when you override `__send__` then there is a warning message

> warning: redefining `__send__` may cause serious problems

This is because to avoid conflicts, specially in gems or libraries when the context where it will be used is unknown, always use `__send__` instead of send.

2. The difference between send (or `__send__`) and public_send is that send / `__send__` can call an object’s private methods, and public_send can’t.

```
class Foo
   def __send__(*args, &block)
       "__send__"
   end
   def send(*args)
     "send"
   end
   def bar
       "bar"
   end
   private
   def private_bar
     "private_bar"
   end
end

Foo.new.bar #=> "bar"
Foo.new.private_bar #=> NoMethodError(private method 'private_bar' called for #Foo)

Foo.new.send(:bar) #=> "send"
Foo.new.__send__(:bar) #=> "__send__"
Foo.new.public_send(:bar) #=> "bar"

Foo.new.send(:private_bar) #=> "send"
Foo.new.__send__(:private_bar) #=> "__send__"
Foo.new.public_send(:private_bar) #=> NoMethodError(private method 'private_bar' called for #Foo)
```

**At the end try to use public_send to avoid direct call to private method instead of using __send__ or send.**