# Ruby DRbObject and overriding send

Tags: ruby, overriding, send, drb

I had a funny situation today (simplified):

Ive a communication object of type `Adapter`, with a `#send` and a `#receive` method.
My application communicates with it by DRb.
So in my application, I have a `DRbObject`, lets say `foo`.

Now, calling

```
foo.send(msg, dest)
```

calls the `#send` on `DRbObject`, instead of `Adapter`.

Most easy fix would be of course to rename the send method.
But, I'd like to stay as close to my documentation/underlying API as possible.

What do you think?
Should I rename the `send` method, or is there a neat (local) hack for this?

Comment: Why would you expect `send` to call the `Adapter` function if it is a `DRbObject` ?

Comment: Have mercy, whatever you do, do not override ``send`` method. Or do it if you have a great idea in mind. But if you don't, stay content with defining eg. ``send_something`` and ``receive_something``.

Comment: @oldergod. The code starting the `Adapter` starts a DRb server so my application can communicate with the the adapter by having a DRbObject connecting to the same uri. like this: http://segment7.net/projects/ruby/drb/introduction.html

Comment: @Boris, You might be right. But it feels ugly, something with programming INTO a language vs IN a language :)
I think the safest thing to do in this case is go for renaming to 'send_message' (or 'puts' or 'transmit' whatever)

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot: No, not ``puts``, pleeese.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Haha, i meant 'put'. I went for `sent_message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DRbObject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb/DRbObject.html#method-i-method_missing) does it's remote message routing magic with `#method_missing`. So, clearly, we should [undefine](http://www.nach-vorne.de/2008/2/28/undef_method-remove_method/) the `#send` method from `foo` so it will delegate to `#method_missing` instead!

`foo.singleton_class.class_eval { undef_method :send }`

Or to do it in a more object-oriented way:

```
AdapterDRbObject < DRbObject
  undef_method :send
end
```

As for whether you *should* do this, that's up for debate.

It's actually "okay" to override/remove `#send`, because everyone is [supposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658269/ruby-send-vs-send) to know that you should always call `#__send__` instead. (In fact, if you look at `DRbObject#method_missing`, it calls `#__send__`.)

On the other hand, `#send` is a pretty core concept of Ruby and might confuse future maintainers of the code.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as accepted answer because this probably was the answer I was looking at at the time. I however, choose to rename it, as Boris suggested