# Ruby: Access member variable with string (Reflection)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reflection

I have a Ruby object User, which has a :first_name member variable. I would like to be able to access that variable with a string.

So if I have a user called u:

`u.'first_name'` should be equivalent to `u.first_name`

How could I use reflection to get u.first_name through the string, which is passed in as a variable?

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is no such thing as a "member variable" in Ruby. There are only global variables (also thread-local global variables and method-local global variables), constants, class variables, instance variables, local variables, and the pseudo-variables `self`, `nil`, `true`, and `false`. `u.first_name` is a message send, it has nothing to do with variables.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you mean with "member variable", is that you have a model that has an attribute called `first_name`. If so, then you can access that attribute as you'd do in a "plain" ("plain" because the question is focused to Rails) Ruby class:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

foo = Foo.new('bar')
p foo.instance_variables             # [:@name]
p foo.instance_variable_get('@name') # "bar"
```

The [most idiomatic way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1077682/5025116) to get dynamically an instance variable is using `instance_variable_get`, but you can also use `send`, or better using [`__send__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4658359/5025116), or [even better](http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/05/05/metaprogramming-dynamic-methods-using-public-send/) in your case using `public_send`:

```
foo = Foo.new('bar')
p foo.instance_variables             # [:@name]
p foo.instance_variable_get('@name') # "bar"
p foo.send('name')                   # "bar"
p foo.public_send('name')            # "bar"
```

The way Rails handles your models and attributes is *almost the same* (NOTE: opened to edition). By instantiating one of your models, you can get the attribute you need:

```
user = User.first
user.email                # email@mail.com
user.public_send('email') # email@mail.com
```