# Ruby, pointer to method

Tags: ruby, pointers, methods

Ruby toddler here (3 days playing with Ruby, probably my terminology is yet imprecise).

For study reason I would like to modify the following code to accept `ticket.request("triple",10)` (or equivalent syntax) in the second last line.

Is it possible (without heavily changing `ticket.request`)?

```rb
ticket = Object.new

def ticket.price
  return 3.5
end

def ticket.triple(c)
  return 3*c
end

# direct call
puts ticket.triple(10)   # ===> 30

# pointer to method
pt = ticket.method(:triple)  
puts pt.call(10)         # ===> 30


def ticket.request(request)    # <=== should it be modified?
  if self.respond_to?(request)
    self.__send__(request)
  end # nil otherwise
end

puts [
   ticket.price,            # direct ===> 3.5
   ticket.request("price"), # safe   ===> 3.5
   ticket.request("name")   # it does not exist ===> nil
 # ticket.request("triple", 10)   <========================= syntax ????
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you need `ticket.request` method to take also arguments you want to be passed to subsequent method call? It is possible, if so:

```
def ticket.request(request, *args)
  if respond_to?(request)
    send(request, *args)
  end
end
puts [
  ticket.price,            # direct ===> 3.5
  ticket.request("price"), # safe   ===> 3.5
  ticket.request("name")   # it does not exist ===> nil
  ticket.request("triple", 10) 
]
```

`*args` in method definition works as "take the rest of arguments and store them in `args` array. In the method call it works in quite opposite way - as "take `args` array and make it an argument list passed into the method".

Note that I deleted redundant `self` keywords, as `self` is default receiver of the message. I also used `send` method, as it's used more commonly.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def ticket.request(request, *args)
  if self.respond_to?(request)
    self.__send__(request, *args)
  end
end
```

Comment: I completely missed it and was quite obvious (later)
Thank you

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [question about `send` vs `__send__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658269/ruby-send-vs-send). I thought the OP used `__send__` for a reason. I would suggest using `public_send` or at least `send` if possible.